# Using dictionaries as 0 index-based sets

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I am mapping a set of arbitrary indexes onto another set where the indexes start in 0. For the moment I have done it so using the following code (cipher is the solution):

```
[In]  t = [(3, 1, 2, 2), (3, 2, 4, 4), (6, 3, 4, 4)]  ## Original set indexes
[Out] r =  set ([i for sublist in t for i in sublist] )
[In]  r =  set([1, 2, 3, 4, 6])                       ## Set of indexes
[In]  cipher = dict(zip(r, range(len(r))))
[Out] cipher {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 6: 4}           ## Solution (Mapping key)
```

However since the keys in a dictionary must be unique, I am trying to create the "cipher" without using a set.

```
[In]  t = [(3, 1, 2, 2), (3, 2, 4, 4), (6, 3, 4, 4)]  ## Original set indexes
[Out] r =  [i for sublist in t for i in sublist] 
[In]  r =  [3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4]       ## Flattened list
[In]  cipher = dict(zip(r, 'count +1 for each new key' ))
[Out] cipher {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 6: 4}           ## Mapping key
```

So for each key added to the dictionary, add a value equal to the length of the dictionary at that moment. I don't know if that is possible?

EDIT

I did what Martijn Pieters says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172532/unique-list-set-to-dictionary?rq=1), but I get the keys and values swapped and a -1 key at the end. It seems a bit too advance for me, so I'm just going to go with what I have.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count
from functools import partial

keymapping = defaultdict(partial(next, count(-1)))
outputdict = {keymapping[v]: v for v in r}

[Out] {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 6, -1: 1}
```

Comment: What are you trying to get ?

Comment: cipher would be the solution. It thought I could maybe speed things up a bit by omitting the creation of a set. It seems a bit redundant to create a set, if the dictionary already creates one...

Comment: I'm a bit confused between what you actually have at the moment and what you are trying to get.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. It looks like you have what you need already judging from the comments and stuff. How about you do this: Write down a few sets of: input, expected output, actual output. Then we can figure out what you want

Comment: Seems the answer is here[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172532/unique-list-set-to-dictionary?rq=1) . But I starts form 1 instead of cero.

Comment: I still can't tell what you want. Fill in the missing parts of the sentence that follows: "Given the input [(3, 1, 2, 2), (3, 2, 4, 4), (6, 3, 4, 4)], I want the following output {???????}"

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You have

```
>>> t = [(3, 1, 2, 2), (3, 2, 4, 4), (6, 3, 4, 4)]
```

First you want these flattened:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> flattened = chain(*t)
```

Then made into a set

```
>>> index_set = set(flattened)
>>> index_set
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 6])
```

Then sort it (sets are not sorted)

```
>>> index_list = sorted(index_set)
```

And then want to assign a new value from 0 to each number here

```
>>> cipher = { k: v for i in v, k in enumerate(index_list) }
>>> cipher
{1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 6: 4}
```